# Returned Object is null Java

Tags: java

I've created an object inside a method and inside main. I want the object inside of the method to be returned. I thought everything in Java was returned by reference not value, so I'm not quite sure how to do this.

```
public class Measurement
{
    private int value;
    private String units; 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Measurement a = new Measurement(2,"cm");
         Measurement b = new Measurement(5,"cm");
         Measurement c = new Measurement();

         c = a.mult(b); 
    }

    public Measurement mult(Measurement aObject)
    {
         Measurement c = new Measurement();

         c.value = this.value * aObject.value;
         c.unit = this.unit; 

         return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks like correct to me, also if you don't need `Measurement c = new Measurement()` since you are returning a new `Measurement` from the `mult` method, so the just created one is lost.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with this line **c.unit = this.unit;** I don't see a _unit_ variable in this class or any method that assigns _unit_ a value

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is the error message?

Comment: What are the types of value and units? You can paste the actual code...

Comment: Note, just for future reference:  [Java is ***always*** pass-by-value.  No exceptions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/1079354)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand how to declare class-level variables. You CANNOT declare variables like this:

```
private unit;
private value;
```

A class-level variable (or field) declaration takes the following form:

```
[modifiers] (variable type) (name);
```

Where the things in the the [] are optional. And I think your declaration lacks a variable type! You should add the word `int` and `String`:

```
private int value;
private String unit;
```

And that's it! Your other code looks pretty normal. I think the only error is the variable declarations.

Comment: Actually it did have a type declaration, I just forgot type it in.